# iis requests authentication when using a domain name on the local machine

Tags: authentication, asp.net, iis-7.5

I'm trying to develop a very simple asp.net web-forms site, using Yahoo! as an external identity provider. The user clicks on a link to Yahoo!, and after identifying on Yahoo! login page, Yahoo! redirect the user to the site with a token identifying the user as a URL parameter.

When I'm on localhost, it works fine. The problem is Yahoo redirects to a domain, which also points to my machine (it's actually a no-ip.org sub-domain). At this point, IE pops a message saying "The server  at Default: admin/1234 requires a username and password". No password that I enter satisfies it, and the request is not reaching the application.

How do I get rid of this message, and let the request get throu to my application?

I'm pretty certain I don't have an "admin" user on the system.

The whole thing is just two pages, one with a link to Yahoo! and one landing page to which Yahoo! redirects. It's only purpose is to collect the token, for an unrelated library i'm working on.

I'm running on Win7 Home edition, with IIS 7.5, Visual Studio 2012 Web Express and .NET 4.5.

Thanks.

Comment: Developing apps is off topic for this site, but I strongly suspect that not only is your home/office router misconfigured to allow remote configuration, it's telling anyone that connects the default username and password so they can log in and take over your router.

Comment: Thanks @DerfK, you pointed me at the right direction. I hadn't realized this is a router issue. It actually isn't set to allow remote configuration, and entering the username/password doesn't let me in. Still, I configured it to direct web requests to my machine, and now the site accepts the request.